# Terraform : depends_on argument not creating the specified resource first

Tags: terraform

I want to push the terraform state file to a github repo. The file function in Terraform fails to read .tfstate files, so I need to change their extension to .txt first. Now to automate it, I created a null resource which has a provisioner to run the command to copy the tfstate file as a txt file in the same directory. I came across this 'depends_on' argument which lets you specify if a particular resource needs to be made first before running the current. However, it is not working and I am straight away getting the error that 'terraform.txt' file doesn't exit when the file function demands it.

```
provider "github" {
  token = "TOKEN"
  owner = "USERNAME"
}

resource "null_resource" "tfstate_to_txt" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "copy terraform.tfstate terraform.txt"
  }
}

resource "github_repository_file" "state_push" {
  repository = "TerraformStates"
  file       = "terraform.tfstate"
  content    = file("terraform.txt")

  depends_on = [null_resource.tfstate_to_txt]
}
```

Comment: Adding state file to git repo (hopefully not public) is not a good practice. Can you clarify what do you want to achieve? Maybe there is better way?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, it's a private repo. I just want to run a script in terraform BEFORE pushing something to git. It can be any file not necessarily a tfstate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The documentation for the `file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html) explains this behavior:

> This function can be used only with files that already exist on disk at the beginning of a Terraform run. Functions do not participate in the dependency graph, so this function cannot be used with files that are generated dynamically during a Terraform operation. We do not recommend using dynamic local files in Terraform configurations, but in rare situations where this is necessary you can use [the `local_file` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/data-sources/file) to read files while respecting resource dependencies.

This paragraph also includes a suggestion for how to get the result you wanted: use the `local_file` data source, from [the `hashicorp/local` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local), to read the file as a resource operation (during the apply phase) rather than as part of configuration loading:

```
resource "null_resource" "tfstate_to_txt" {
  triggers = {
    source_file = "terraform.tfstate"
    dest_file   = "terraform.txt"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "copy ${self.triggers.source_file} ${self.triggers.dest_file}"
  }
}

data "local_file" "state" {
  filename = null_resource.tfstate_to_txt.triggers.dest_file
}

resource "github_repository_file" "state_push" {
  repository = "TerraformStates"
  file       = "terraform.tfstate"
  content    = data.local_file.state.content
}
```

---

Please note that although the above should get the order of operations you were asking about, reading the `terraform.tfstate` file while Terraform running is a very unusual thing to do, and is likely to result in undefined behavior because Terraform can repeatedly update that file at unpredictable moments throughout `terraform apply`.

If your intent is to have Terraform keep the state in a remote system rather than on local disk, the usual way to achieve that is to configure [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html), which will then cause Terraform to keep the state *only* remotely, and not use the local `terraform.tfstate` file at all.

Answer (score 6):

`depends_on` does not really work with `null_resource.provisioner`.

here's a workaround that can help you :

```
   resource "null_resource" "tfstate_to_txt" {
        provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "copy terraform.tfstate terraform.txt"
         }
       }
        
   resource "null_resource" "delay" {
        provisioner "local-exec" {
            command = "sleep 20"
         }
        triggers = {
            "before" = null_resource.tfstate_to_txt.id
         }
        }
  resource "github_repository_file" "state_push" {
        repository = "TerraformStates"
        file       = "terraform.tfstate"
        content    = file("terraform.txt")
        depends_on = ["null_resource.delay"]
       }
```

the delay null resource will make sure the resource 2 runs after the first if the copy command takes more time just change the sleep to higher number

Comment: Thank you. Thank works for me but kept updating sleep till 60